# Convert SQL Server text to sql_handle

Tags: sql-server, handle

I know how to get a SQL statement from a `sql_handle`, using `CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle);`, but how I can get the `sql_handle` from a SQL statement?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get the `sql_handle` from the text of a batch but it isn't easy.

The 44-byte `sql_handle` has the following components (in order):

1. 4 bytes: Byte-reversed integer code for the target cache e.g.

   0x02000000 (2) for SQL Plans (`CACHESTORE_SQLCP`)
   0x03000000 (3) for Object Plans (`CACHESTORE_OBJCP`)
2. 4 bytes: Byte-reversed integer object id

   For adhoc and prepared SQL this is an **internal hash** of the batch text as returned by `@@PROCID` or `objectid` in `sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes`.
3. 16 bytes: MD5 hash of the batch text including parameter definitions as a prefix (if present).
4. 20 bytes 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

If you need the undocumented internal hash of the batch text, it is listed in https://www.sql.kiwi/2020/10/sqlhandle-and-sql-server-batch-text-hash.html by Paul White.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way if you research how that DMV works internally. If I needed a quick and dirty answer I would do this:

```
With cteQueries As
(
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs  
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st  
)
Select * From cteQueries Where text 
      = 'INSERT msdb.dbo.syssessions(agent_start_date) VALUES(GetDate()) SELECT session_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()'
```